# What does $\sigma$ mean in this context?

Tags: matrices

This is a problem taken straight from my Numerical Methods course :

Prove that :
$\sigma (A^{-1})$ =  { $\frac{1} {\lambda_1} ,\frac{1} {\lambda_1}, ... ,\frac{1} {\lambda_n} $ } .

However, nothing is mentioned about the notation,  can anyone enlighten me as to what does the problem really ask ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sigma$ probably mean the spectrum here: so you have to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !